# Phase difference in stationary wave

Tags: waves

I know that the particles within a loop are in phase (Phase difference -0°)with each other and antiphase (180°) with the particles in the next loop. Then what about the phase difference of two adjacent nodes or antinode

Answer (score -1):

Between two nodes the phase difference remains 0 whereas between antinodes the phase difference is 180.